# German umlauts issue on receiving as response from .net Webservice to Java application

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, character-encoding, jersey-2.0

I am facing a strange issue. German **"Umlauts"** not displayed properly "�����"in the Webpages when it is obtained from a .net Web service.

**Scenario:** 
We have .Net Web-service running in Client region( say Swiss/ German) and in Development region(India). Both are same code.

We are consuming some data , say list objects via web-service in a Java web application (jsf +Jersey, Maven project). 
The Java application is an compiled war,deployed using tomcat in both region (Note: War files same at both end)

**Issue:** 
When the list object contains a String with German characters **"Umlauts"** then it is not displayed properly in the Webpages. it's rendering as "�����".

This issue happens only in the Swiss region not in India.

When we try to hit the web-service directly via Browser not via our Java application, it's returning the same list with German characters **"Umlauts"** , which rendered properly in browser.It working in both region correctly by direct webservice hit using browser.

But it fails when hit performed via our java application. only in  client region.

Java App Encoding used : **UTF-8**
Web-service Soap Response: **UTF-8**

Comment: First thing to find out: is the problem getting the value from the web service, or displaying it? Log the string in detail (on a test server!) - each UTF-16 code unit in it - before you display it. If the data looks okay at that point, then the problem is in how you're sending the response and you can cut out the web service part of the problem... you should be able to see the same issue with a hard-coded string. If the data is broken already, then you can cut out the serving side, and write a console app which *just* hits the web service to try to diagnose the issue further.

Comment: Basically, until you know which "side" the problem is on, it's going to be a *lot* harder to fix.

Comment: @JonSkeet I tried the above approaches too. I tried with hard coded String with German characters. it rendered properly in Browser. I tried with debugging the code where the response is assigned to the variable. the response string  contains � characters when received from web-service. I tried with console app to hit web-service, but same string  contains � characters.  But the webservice returns the exact german character when hit directly via browser. This is comletely strange and this issue happens only in client region.

Comment: @JonSkeet  Application is multilingual and it has the German text by default , but there is no issue on rendering those values. This Issue happens only when the German string were received via web-service.

Comment: Right, so in that case it sounds like your serving part is irrelevant, and you should use the console app you've written to help diagnose exactly what's wrong. The next step would be to use something like Wireshark to see the exact bytes on the wire, both for the request and the response.